# Component lost during rerender, how to reattach?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am rendering a component into a grid rowExpander plugin rowBodyTpl:

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'rowexpander',
    rowBodyTpl : [
        '<div id="contact-row-{Id}"> </div>'
    ]
}],


var row = 'contact-row-' + record.get('Id'),
    grid = Ext.getCmp(gridId),
    if(!grid) me.createSubGrid(record,gridId).render(row);
```

This works fine. But when the grid receives an `update` event for a record with certain modifiedFields, that record's rowExpander is rerendered using the rowTpl only, and the inner grid is dangling somewhere. I can access the grid using Ext.getCmp, and `grid.rendered` is true, but it is not shown. So I guess I have to reattach the grid after the row has been rerendered.

I think I can attach to the update event, and find out whether the rowTpl has been rerendered without the child grid using

```
if(!grid.container.contains(grid.el))
```

But is there a way to put the grid back into the dom?

I have tried

```
grid.container.insertFirst(grid.el);
```

but this does not work. The element is inserted but the grid is not displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my trials, I already was on the right track, and the error was somewhere else entirely. The problem was that my update event fn which did the reattach was executed before the update event fn that broke everything, because the fn was fired on the same event and had the same priority, but was attached to the store earlier. Changing the priority was one option, but I just put the creation into the boxready event, which is executed after the view has attached its events to the store:

```
xtype:'grid',
listeners:{
    boxready:function(grid) {
        var store = grid.getStore();
        ...
        store.on({
            update:function(store, record) {
                me.restoreSubgridDom(record);
            },
            beforeload:function(store) {
                var records = store.getRange();
                Ext.each(records,me.destroySubgrid);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with the two functions:

```
restoreSubgridDom: function(record) {
    var row = 'contact-row-' + record.get('Id'),
        gridId = 'ContactRow'+record.get('Id')+'Grid',
        grid = Ext.getCmp(gridId);
    if(grid && !grid.container.contains(grid.el))
    {
        grid.container.insertFirst(grid.el);
    }
},
destroySubgrid: function(record) {
    var gridId = 'ContactRow'+record.get('Id')+'Grid',
        grid = Ext.getCmp(gridId);
    if(grid) grid.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing leads to memory leaks (because your component is not destroy when the grid is re-render).

I suggest to check at : Component Template (http://skirtlesden.com/ux/ctemplate) or if you try to render a nested grid, there was several attempt to build something correct and I think a working one is the following : http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2015/06/30/nested-grid-in-sencha-ext-js/

Comment: Thanks for your input. The CTemplate is ExtJS4 only and does not longer work in ExtJS6. I guess someone should be able to implement something similar for ExtJS6, but I am not. The working example from that blog post looks very similar to what I did. But in that case, `update` event is not fired because the parent grid rows cannot be edited (he is only editing child grid rows, which does NOT fire an update event on the parent grid row). I think that the problems addressed in the blog post are already resolved in ExtJS6 which I am using - at least I had no problem clicking into the child grid.

Comment: I'm using CTemplate and I'm working with ExtJS 6 also ;). (and I did not modify it, I've just check). Good luck for the rest!